# Asp.Net Web Form calling same domain WCF service without need for authentication

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a aspnetcompatibility=true WCF service (http binding) in the same domain of my Asp.Net website.

I want to make a call from my Asp.Net server side code to the WCF service.

I have tried to make a web request to `http://testDomain/mySite/services/mySvc.svc` but got the login page instead.

Is there a way to call the wcf service from the same domain asp.net site so that the service knows to not authenticate again?

Note: I use IIS7, and I'm open to change by binding as long as I can make a call to it w/o authentication. I'm hoping to host the svc in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable windows authentication in IIS for your hosted service and disable anonymous authentication (if it is enabled). Besides, pass security credentials (domain credentials perhaps in your case) from the client to the service.

Comment: if you really want to avoid any authentication, the you can set the security mode to None and enable anonymous authentication in IIS. It should work.